# angularjs $scope not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After going over the tutorial videos and documentation for a few times, my data binding doesn't seem to be in effect. I'm relatively new to the language, so could someone explain to me what I did wrong? (I'm trying to implement using $scope, and not as an alias for my controller). I have attached my HTML, and my javascript.

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="DishDetailController">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
           <div class="media-list">
                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                    <a href="#">
                    <img class="media-object img-thumbnail"
                     ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                     <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                     <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span></h2>
                    <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                    <br><br>
                    <p> <strong>Customer Comments</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Sort by:
                       <input type="text" ng-model="userOrder" accept="" placeholder="Filter by" autofocus></p>
                    <span>{{dish}}</span>
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
             <div class="media-list" ng-repeat="comment in dish.comments | orderBy:userOrder">
                 <ul>
                <blockquote>
                  <p>{{comment.rating}} Stars</p>
                   <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
                    <footer>By {{comment.author}} on {{comment.date | date:'mediumDate'}} </footer>
                </blockquote>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
        .controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.dish={
                      name:'Uthapizza',
                      image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                      category: 'mains',
                      label:'Hot',
                      price:'4.99',
                      description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                       comments: [
                           {
                               rating:5,
                               comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                               author:"John Lemon",
                               date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                               author:"Paul McVites",
                               date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:3,
                               comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                               author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                               date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                               author:"Ringo Starry",
                               date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:2,
                               comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                               author:"25 Cent",
                               date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           }

                       ]
                };

    }])
```

Comment: Any error? And the data-binding are not working or partial?

Comment: Not sure, is your example missing a  closing </div> tag perhaps?

Comment: it's not really clear what your issue is; I was able to recreate your code without any issue in a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/9mLxJrX94lvkRJT0leiU?p=preview/ with the exception of adding a few ending `<div>` tags and an `ng-app` missing from your example.

Comment: it's not a closing div problem, if u see a lack of div, it is because I took it out of a bigger code, so it cant be that.

Comment: So I think more than ever the question here is, what isn't working? The code you posted here does not exhibit any flaws when run independently, as shown in the plunker I linked in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have your objects in an array, so the expressions need to access them as such.

Example, to access the second `comment` in your `comments` array:

```
<footer>By {{comment.author}} on {{comment.date | date:'mediumDate'}} </footer>
```

should be:

```
<footer>By {{comments[1].comment.author}} on {{comments[1].comment.date | date:'mediumDate'}} </footer>
```

**EDIT:** As has been pointed out, there is already a repeater (that I overlooked). This answer is moot.

Comment: there is an `ng-repeat` that takes care of that in the HTML already.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. I did not see the repeater.